# ERROR: current transaction is aborte d, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've been trying to run a .sql file in my postgresql. using cmd

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Postgresql\9.3\bin\psql.exe"  -U postgres -d postgres -a -f C:\Sites\xmastool\postgresql.sql
```

but after doing so, several errors appear

```
psql:C:/Sites/xmastool/postgresql.sql:388: ERROR:  current transaction is aborte
    d, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:C:/Sites/xmastool/postgresql.sql:389: ERROR:  current transaction is aborte
    d, commands ignored until end of transaction block, 
psql:C:/Sites/xmastool/postgresql.sql:390: ERROR:  current transaction is aborte
    d, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

And the error goes on.

I don't understand why, can anyone please explain?

I've been stuck for several hours.

I am using windows by the way.

Comment: Perhaps if you look to your SQL file at line 388, you can get more information?

Comment: hello @Houari,
Actually the list goes on from line 389, 390, 391... til 531. I'll update my question :)

Comment: That means that there was a transaction block which within there was an exception thrown, and shoud be handled(Rollback or something), but there was other insrtuction after the error, this is why you get this error messages. You should track where/why the error are thrown first!

Comment: Add `-v ON_ERRROR_STOP=1` to your `psql` command line, so it stops after the first error.

Comment: Hello, First of all thanks for your comments. I did just that and the first error that appears is this 
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
**psql:C:/Sites/xmastool/postgresql.sql:33: ERROR:  relation "accessories_id_seq" does not exist**
 when i researched on it most people who gets the same error are creating a new table and thus most of the errors comes from mixed-case spelling, I'm just pulling data from a database sent to me.